# Save huge arrays to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a page where users can add new input fields, such as

```
<input class="array_moment" name="MEd[]" id="MEd1" value="10" />
<textarea name="kommentar[]" id="kommentar1" value=""></textarea>
```

The array can have a size of up to 500, data type is float for input and varchar for textarea.
The array will be stored in MySQL, but how the data should be stored.

I had intended to use json_encode () and json_decode () and store it in a single column field, but is this reasonable?

Comment: No one can answer your question, since you do not specify any details at all about what kind of data, for what purpose, what you plan to do with it.

Comment: The recommendation for database is generally to normalize your data unless you have very specific reasons not to do so

Comment: google 'php batch insert', that should put you on the right track

Comment: Do you ever need only part of the data?

Comment: you can use json or serialized data in DB.

Comment: Answer to Sumurai8: No I always need all the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use server side script to translate this array to sql insert statement, like this:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST["column"]);

foreach($arr as $i){

$sql="insert into tmptable values({$i})";

sql_exec($sql);
}
```

and you can save the keys as well.